# ClearQuest Perl : how to clear a list of values? SetFieldValue doesn't work on lists

Tags: perl, clearquest

New to Perl and new to ClearQuest Perl API both. I am trying to clear some values from a CQ form. I am able to clear values by simply setting the value to "" but it doesn't work on lists. Any idea how this can be done?

```
# following doesn't work on lists. What to do? 

    $entity->SetFieldValue("Foo_List", "");


# following works just fine

    $entity->SetFieldValue("barstatus", "");
```

Here is **CQ API** reference:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/r_examples_mangngrecrds.htm

Comment: Not sure how to use undef in this scneario. I am accessing "Foo_List" through entity object. It's not directly available to me. Or is it? I thought I can only use entity->MehodName to operate on Foo_List. (Sorry, I am new to Perl)

Comment: I mean `$entity->setFieldValue("Foo_List", undef);`

Comment: correct link for API should be: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/c_entity_mthds.htm

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your API, the **undef** is unlikely to work. **setFieldValue** can not be called on a list to begin with. I don't know much Perl either. But try creating a loop to read all values, and delete each value using **DeleteFieldValue** method of entity object. 
All methods of entity objects are listed here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/c_entity_mthds.htm

I don't know Perl syntax well. But someone here may be able to help.

hth.